# Google Web Toolkit plugin is not working for chrome browser

Tags: gwt, plugins

I am a new user of Google Web Toolkit.
I tried to run my application in chrome browser.
But it was asking me to download the plugin to run GWT applications.
Then i gone through the link but it was showing me this problem....NOT COMPATIBLE

[image]

Please provide help.

Answer (score 3):

[Release Notes for 2.6.1](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_1)

> GWT Development Mode will no longer be available for Chrome sometime
>   in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are
>   improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error
>   messages.

[enter link description here](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html)

Comment: can you provide some information about how to test my gwt application?

Comment: @mohit-tiwari Follow the docs about DevMode; differences are a) you don't need a plugin, and b) you need to debug inside the browser dev tools (make sure source maps are enabled so you can see your Java code instead of JS)

Comment: yeah finally you got your answer so please close this question by accept the answer